# What's the common practice for reuse/discarding of Adox Rodinal developer solution?

Tags: film, developing, chemicals, development, rodinal

I am making a 1+50 solution (total 500ml) from [Adox Rodinal concentrate](https://www.fotoimpex.com/chemistry/adox-rodinal-500-ml-concentrate.html).

In common practice do you keep and reuse this 500ml  solution 
or discard it every time we use?

If re-use how long can we keep the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adox Rodinal is a one shot developer, meaning it is not meant to be reused (https://www.adox.de/Photo/adox-film-developer/rodinal-adonal/).

Mix up your 1+50 for your immediate needs and discard when done developing.

Check your local laws for instructions on discarding, as this will vary from place to place. For example, my city doesn’t care about used dev or stop going down the tap, but used fix must be stored separately and recycled.

Comment: @Huesco Thanks. Does also apply for Adox-Adofix Plus Fixer concentrate? Create solution for need and through right away after use.

Comment: @neversaint: no, you never use fixer like that.  [Adox](http://www.adox.de/Photo/adox-chemistry/stopbath-and-fixer/adofix/) say that a litre of concentrate will do about 90 films (I presume they mean 35mm films, although I think 35mm and 120 have about the same area).

Comment: @neversaint In general, there are one shot and replenishment type developers. Stop, fix, hypoclear, and wetting agents are usually mixed up and reused until exhaustion, which takes more than just the one roll of film.

Comment: Yes, 120 and 135 films have roughly the same area. 135 is longer and winds more tightly on spool & it sits a tad lower in your tank, so you need a little less liquid to cover it fully, but as far as fixer capacity is concerned they are interchangeable.